# Animate button to match_parent without replacing button's text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a menu consisting of 5 buttons with color background (width set to match_parent, and height to wrap_content).

I want it to fill all the screen with the background color after i click it with the button's text either staying on his place or moving slovly to center.

After a lots of searching for different animation methods i picked that one

```
    Transition changeBounds = new ChangeBounds();
    changeBounds.setDuration(1000);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(landingScreenLayout, changeBounds);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams sizeRules = mButton.getLayoutParams();
    mButton.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

I chose it because animating it with "scale" stretches the button's text. But the problem is, that when i start animating it, its text immediately goes to the center, what ruins everything - obliviously

Any help appreciated ;)

Edit: oh, and i've already forgot - i tried to make this 'button'/menu item with a RelativeLayout and TextView - what worked, but it looked horribly dirty in XML and i wouldn't want to go that way

Comment: could you elaborate on "I want it to fill all the screen with the background color after i click it with the button's text either staying on his place or moving slovly to center.", perhaps with pictures?

Comment: Is it ok if i send a video here?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8hLwCmLp-4

As you can see the WHERE text immediately switched its position to center. I want it to stay either in the same place or move smoothly to center